# MySQL: SQL JOIN, COUNT, and WHERE statements

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, where-clause

Currently, I am trying to join two tables (named pageviews and sessions) and use the COUNT and WHERE conditions in order to identify new users that used the site (on a specific page) from the previous two weeks. For reference, the two tables date back from the previous 12 months. In order to do so, I have written the following query

```
SELECT pageviews.pageType
     , sessions.sessionDate
     , sessions.deviceType
     , COUNT(visitorId)
FROM sessions 
INNER JOIN pageviews 
   on sessions.sessionId = pageviews.sessionId
WHERE pageviews.pageType = 'Page1' 
  AND sessionDate BETWEEN '2018-04-26' AND '2018-05-08'
   =! visitorId BETWEEN '2017-05-10' AND '2018-04-27' 
ORDER BY sessionsDate;
```

I decided to join the two tables by session ID so I can dedicate COUNT to visitorId. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

Comment: you have a typo   what mean ? AND '2018-05-08'=! visitorId ?

Comment: That `WHERE` clause is completely malformed. You need to correct that before we can answer any questions.

Comment: Wich version of SQL Server are you using? To identify which T-SQL is

Comment: Um... aggregration w/o a group by seems a bit off as well... Perhaps an analytic function instead...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  The lack of a `GROUP BY` clause and the `SELECT` expressions are particularly curious, given the question.

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL, I just put the =! instead of <>

Comment: the where condition in your code  seems wrong  ..

Comment: You would want != instead of =!, if that worked here.  != works in T-SQL as well.  But you don't even want that.  Maybe `AND visitorID NOT BETWEEN`

Comment: @TheLeveyBreaks you put SQL Server that uses T-SQL, MySQL uses SQL:2000 it's another notation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL works without GROUP BY =( It's a common mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a group by pageviews.pageType and do the count in the visits, you will have the result per page